# helm fails with failed to create: Secret "sh.helm.release.v1.(release-name).v1" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 character

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install a helm release, using following command

```
helm upgrade --install --reset-values {release-name} ../chart --namespace test01 --values /tmp/values737957648
```

The chart is not packaged is kept in the expanded form.

This fails with the below error, where it basically trying to store release information

```
sh.helm.release.v1.{release-name}.v1" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 characters
```

How to go about debugging this problem?

if I try to generate the template of the chart and do kubectl create it gets installed fine .i.e.

```
helm template {release-name} chart --namespace test01 --values /tmp/values737957648 >> test1.yaml
kubectly create test1.yaml  (No configmap/No secret limit issue)
```

The problem occurs when trying to install via helm and it tries to create helm-secret

How could I approach to solve this issue ?

I am using helm version

```
helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", 
GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}
```

Comment: How big is the values file you're trying to use here?  (Are you trying to inject large config files, via a Helm value, into a ConfigMap?)

Comment: I am mounting db sql files in configmap (and they used to work) ,and they are not crossing the limit of 1 mb as I could create the template (using helm template) and apply it ( using kubeclt create) ofcourse-when using kubeclt helm.sh is not created to maintain histoy.

Answer (score 20):

In my case the root cause was very unexpected: the chart folder contained the xxxx.tgz file (the archive file left there by mistake) and until it was deleted, I got this error all the time. The error message isn't even close to the real root cause.

Comment: After you removed the data over 1 MB, the error disappeared. How does it not describe the root cause? Do note that I agree the error could absolutely be made more helpful.

Comment: As I haven't put this file to the folder explicitly, the root cause was not clear until I had fount the wrong file, that has nothing to do with helm secrets. File had no characters, mentioned as a part of secret details, so... It's not just completely wrong, it is misleading

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's basically an implementation detail that Helm drops the whole chart to K8s as a Secret so that it can know the diff to the next chart version/release (and allow rollback etc.). Currently open relevant issue in Helm repo (but I guess you are the author): https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9788

Comment: God bless Stack-O.

Answer (score 10):

in my case I had a "img/" directory with some images... at weekend I add many big png files... and a similar error appear...

```
% helm upgrade --install {release name} {mychart} -f values-mychart-custom.yaml --debug
    history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release mychart
    Release "mychart" does not exist. Installing it now.
    install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: ""
    install.go:199: [debug] CHART PATH: Library/Caches/helm/repository/mychart-1.0.0.tgz

Error: create: failed to create: Secret "sh.helm.release.v1.mychart.v1" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 bytes
helm.go:88: [debug] Secret "sh.helm.release.v1.mychart.v1" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 bytes
create: failed to create
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage/driver.(*Secrets).Create
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage/driver/secrets.go:164
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage.(*Storage).Create
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage/storage.go:69
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).RunWithContext
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:340
main.runInstall
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:265
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:124
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
```

after a *loooong day* doing an ugly Helm debug, I move the "img/" folder out of the chart directory and all working again....

#### so: please keep your awesome documentation and non-related Helm chart files outside the **charts/*** directories where you are developing your charts...

:)

*The clue: generate manifest files, apply them and check all it's right*

```
% helm template mychart chart --values ./values.yaml > debug.yaml
% kubectl apply -f debug.yaml
% kubectl delete -f debug.yaml
```

Comment: You can add files/directories to .helmignore to help get rid of this error too.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is straight from:
https://jhooq.com/helm-chart-failed-to-create/

**The root cause behind this issue can be one of the following -**

1. Helm release name consists of upper-case (ex - helm install demoChart helloworld)
2. Helm release name consists of blank spaces (ex - helm install demo Chart helloworld)
3. Helm release name consists of special character (ex - helm install demoCh@rt helloworld)

*In my case, I had underscore in my chart name. When I replaced underscores with dashes, chart deployed just fine.*

Comment: This does not answer the question - no mention of "data: Too long" in the linked page.

Comment: I had the same issue with the underscore. Funny how `helm create` does not validate the release name

Answer (score 4):

I did an `du . --block-size=KB` and surprisingly there was a `.kube` folder which had a lot data in it, after removing that the problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Move all files out of helm directory and then try to move them back in small chunks to see which folder/file contains this issue. Alternatively use `du -sh $(ls -A)` command to look for big folders or files.

Adding hidden **.git** directory into **.helmignore** file solved my issue with the same error message as in question title.

.helmignore content example:

```
*.txt
.git
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for met too, after trying everything else.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced a similar issue today and it was because I have some additional files in my helm directory.

ex: debug.log or my_readme.txt

I removed all the files that are not relevant to the helm chart and it worked fine.

**Helm errors are misleading.**

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have any unused helm files in your helm chart folder.
In my case I accidentally downloaded some big-size binary, and it caused similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was .git folder the problem.
Using .helmignore file is the solution to ignore unwanted files:

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/helm_ignore_file/

Comment: Please use proper capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the .tgz file of what you are trying to install worked for me.